# gps alert the user when reaches the particular location

Tags: ios, core-location

I am developing the location based application. I just stop the location manager when user reaches the particular location(which is selected by user). I have tried in all combinations but no luck.Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called **Geofencing**.
It's built-in in CoreLocation and really easy to use.
Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/95014/geofencing-ios-swift).

Comment: I tried this but i need to pass radius for it. I am not interested in passing the radius.

Comment: Put a small radius (like 20 meters)... You won't have perfect precision.